# Can we instantiate a class in itself

Tags: apex

Please see the following code:

```
public class Second_Example {
        integer x;
        integer y;

    public void showLine(){
        Second_Example se1 = new Second_Example();
        system.debug(se1.x);
    }
}
```

Can I instantiate the Second_Example class this way.

Comment: Just a gentle nudge, but this is something you can easily try out in the Developer Console. Do you have a broader question about an implementation pattern that you're concerned with?

Comment: Hi David!! I am new to programming. Simply my question is, can I instantiate a class within itself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but it's relatively less common for you to want to.

In a method like `showLine()`, which is an *instance method*, your code is already executing in the context of a `Second_Example` instance. That instance is accessible via the special variable `this`, although in Apex you are not required to use the `this` keyword to access *instance variables* like `x` and `y`.

So, for example, you could write this:

```
public void showLine(){
    system.debug(this.x);
}
```

or

```
public void showLine(){
    system.debug(x);
}
```

and your debug logs would show the value of `x` in the `Second_Example` instance where this is called. To make that concrete, the invocation would look like this:

```
Second_Example ex = new Second_Example();
ex.x = 1;
ex.y = 2;

ex.showLine();
```

Since `showLine()` is invoked as an instance method of the instance `ex` of the class `Second_Example`, it has access to the member variables `x` and `y` of that instance.

You *can* instantiate new instances of a class within that class's instance methods, as you've written. It's not the most common pattern, but it is legal. It is much more common to see that pattern in *static methods*, which are not bound to a specific instance; this is used to expose functionality to callers without that caller creating an instance:

```
public static void showLine() {
    Second_Example ex = new Second_Example();
    ex.x = 1;
    ex.y = 2;

    ex.showLine();
}
```

Then, some outside caller can do

```
Second_Example.showLine();
```

to execute the functionality.

Comment: David!! thanks for the descriptive and prompt response. So would I be correct if is say that instantiating a class within itself is not a good programming practice. //It will show that the programmer is a newbie.

Comment: Also, can you please explain this line further:

It is much more common to see that pattern in static methods, which are not bound to a specific instance; this is used to expose functionality to callers without that caller creating an instance:

Comment: Faiz, it's not _bad_ programming practice, it's just not the most common pattern that you will see (and I don't think it makes sense in this example). To get used to the core concepts of object-oriented programming, it might be helpful to read through [this section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_understanding.htm) of the Apex Developer Guide, and _also_ check out some introductory references to other object-oriented programming languages, like Java, that do more work to help you learn your way around the concepts of OOP.

Comment: Thanks alot David. I will surely do that. 

One quick question (for the day) is that in Java we see classes being instantiated in static main method(). Is there such a norm in Salesforce apex, where developers usually instantiate a class in a specific class or method. Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Apex does not have a `main()` method, but Apex classes do have [constructors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm) and may choose to use the singleton pattern with a static accessor.